# Disable :hover on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div` that has hover:

```
.div {
  // css
}
.div:hover {
  // css
}
```

But I want to disable the hover when you click on the `div`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Option 1. The Javascript solution

Simply add a class prohibiting the application of hover styling on click:

```js
$('div').on('click', function() { // when you click the div
  $(this).addClass('no-hover'); // add the class 'no-hover'
});
```

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}
div:not(.no-hover):hover { /* only apply hover styling when the div does not have the class 'no-hover' */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hover!</div>
```

### Option 2. The CSS solution

Alternatively, in pure CSS (although without rule persistence)

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}
div:not(:focus):hover {
  color: red;
}
div:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0">hover!</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for the CSS solution. Although you might want to make the `tabindex` value negative. As it is, it will make the `div` the first item in the page's tab order.

Comment: Also, depending on the asker's requirements, you may need to negate the selection of the `:active` pseudo class as well.

Comment: I was about to go with JS. Good that I had seen the option 2. ^_^ @Shaggy You are right. I used the `:not(:active)` instead of `:not(:focus)` because it was not applying the active state for me like selected `span` bar on click.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "without rule persistence"?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:

```
$('[your selector]').css({'pointer-events': 'none'})
```

Comment: it will not remove the click event from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
.disabled {

  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;

}

.disabled:hover *

  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;

}
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('#myid').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $(this).css({background: '#F94'});
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).css({background: '#DDD'});
    },
    click: function(){
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/671/)**

Comment: Note this doesn't maintain strict separation of concerns, e.g. keeping styling outside the scope of JS and keeping within CSS - the application/removal of classes and use of `:hover` state can remedy this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
  $(".div").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(this).addClass("active");      //add the class to the clicked element
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.div.active:hover {
cursor:default;
//same CSS as the DIV

}
```