# remove hover highlighting on click event

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Three steps working for my table row highlighting.

1. on hover the background is highlighted blue.(basically, to show you can highlight it)
2. click event highlights the background row blue.
3. click a highlighted row it un highlights.

These are working good.

**The problem**

When i click a highlighted row to un highlight it wont show that it's un highlighted while the mouse is hovering. Only, on mouse leave.
I need it to be able to disable the hover so it can show that its un highlighted as soon as its clciked to un highlight. Trick is i only need the hover disabled only on that click. I need it to be able to hover again, and go through the same process.

**HTML**

```
<table class="superusertable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody class="table-font">
    <tr ng-init="highlightAllRows(source)" ng-repeat="source in userData"
        ng-model="source.fromSourceID" 
        ng-class="{'sourcesSelected': source.sourcesSelected}" 
        ng-click="select(source)">
   <td width="290px">
  <div class="action-checkbox"; width="290px">{{source.fromSourceID}}
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**angular**

highlight all rows sets all the rows initially highlighted.

```
$scope.highlightAllRows = function(item){
    item.sourcesSelected = true;
};

$scope.select = function(item) {
    item.sourcesSelected = item.sourcesSelected ? false : true;

};
```

**CSS**

```
.superusertable tr:hover{
background-color: #80CCFF !important;
}
```

is there a simple css,jquery, angular solution to disable the hover when highlighted row is clicked. I need hover to work again when you hover back

Comment: Add a class for `highlighted` and `unhiglighted`

Comment: easiest way probably to toggle a class when the element is hovered or clicked?

Comment: hmm im not sure how

Comment: The answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118246/disable-hover-on-click) looks like it may be of use to you.

Comment: That disables the hover and you cant use hover again. I need to be able to hover again. you can play with that answer to see what i mean. I actually used google before posting here.

Comment: In general, instead of changing background color, use `cursor: pointer` to indicate an element is clickable.

Comment: I think thats a good idea