# Remove css hover effect on click Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hover, click

This code seems not to work.

The text stays blue on hover, but I want it to be red instead after clicking this text.

Tried several actions, but none of them works

```js
$('.secondary').click(function() {
  $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style media="screen">
  .secondary {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .secondary:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>

<div class="secondary">
  CLICK ME TO BE RED
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can't do that, you need to apply delete class of element

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118246/disable-hover-on-click

Comment: Also .unbind is deprecated for .off had it worked (line .bind is deprecated for .on)

Comment: Thank you for the reminder Leo. couldn't find it any more.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.secondary').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.secondary {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

.hover:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="secondary hover">
  CLICK ME TO BE RED
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and remove said events with a `click` event as well, like so:

```js
$('.secondary').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'blue');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  },
  click: function() {
    $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style media="screen">
  .secondary {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
  }
</style>

<div class="secondary">
  CLICK ME TO BE RED
</div>
```

I would suggest adding/removing a class with your preferred styling instead of applying CSS through JavaScript, though. You can achieve that like so:

```js
$('.secondary').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).addClass('is-blue');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).removeClass('is-blue');
  },
  click: function() {
    $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).removeClass('is-blue');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style media="screen">
  .secondary {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .secondary.is-blue {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>

<div class="secondary">
  CLICK ME TO BE RED
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sigurd, great ideas. Although this text stays blue after the click; The idea suggested by Leo the Lion on my initial post makes the trick possible, by  using pure css.